# How to add a animation in cardview android?

Tags: android, android-cardview

How to add an animation in **CardView** of android, if I click on CardView I want to show some animation.

This is the xml for CardView which I created for CardView. How to add an animation inside this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_icon"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#848484"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_icon"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this piece of code in your card view and create an `animation.xml` and call in

```
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/animation"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/animation"
        android:clickable="true"
```

**animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- animate the translationZ property of a view when pressed -->
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:state_enabled="true"
            android:state_pressed="true">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:propertyName="translationZ"
                    android:valueTo="6dp"
                    android:valueType="floatType"/>
            </set>
        </item>
        <item>
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:propertyName="translationZ"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"/>
            </set>
        </item>
    </selector>
</set>
```

Similarly, you can use any type of animation

Comment: I tried, but I'm not getting that what effect should come? Any example?